# Anyone have good information on Microsoft Kojax?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Has anyone in the SO community had an opportunity to learn more about, or get any hands on exposure to Microsoft Kojax?  It is way early, but are there any resources out there about this technology (Publicly available on the web)?

[ZDNet Article on Kojax](http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=1741)

From the article:
"Kojax is a mobile development platform, according to my sources, that will allow Microsoft- — and third-party-developed — applets run in an Ajax-like way, using a combination of Visual Studio tools and JavaScript, on Java-based mobile phones."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's highly unlikely that Microsoft will release "Kojax" any time within the next year and a half, particularly since none of it has even been discussed outside of Microsoft's 4 walls.  It sounds basically like Silverlight for mobile, and considering Silverlight is still pretty raw after a couple years, I don't think Kojax will be anything earth shattering.

But I'd love to be proven wrong. =)

Comment: I guess WP7 proved you were wrong :)

Comment: I don't think you understood Kojax.  WP7 has nothing to do with making apps run on Java-based mobile phones (which is what Kojax was supposed to be).  WP7 apps are in either XNA or Silverlight, not Java.

Comment: My bad. I didn't read the whole question to the end :( Thanks for the correction @Jess